# To create Alert Rule in log analytics workspace with logic app as a action name

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-log-analytics, alerts

In our project need, we are looking to trigger a Logic app workflow from Log Analytics workspace alerts, whenever an error/exception gets logged in log Analytics workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select action type as Logic App for an action group. And then use that action group for your alerts.

1. Go to alerts > Manage action groups to create an action group and select Logic App action as shown in the picture below.

[image]

2. Create an alert to get triggered based on a log analytics query and associate the action group from step 1 with this alert.

Comment: Thank You Tarun,This answer helped me alot

Comment: Great! Can you please mark this as accepted answer.